# Import File in Python Package

Tags: python, python-module, python-packaging

How would I go about importing another file in a python package. I install the package with

```
pip install .
```

so I can then run it using

```
python3 -m pkg
```

Here's the file structure:
.
├── pkg
│⠀⠀├── cli.py
│⠀⠀├── __init__.py
│⠀⠀├── __main__.py
├── README.md
└── setup.py

I try to import a function from cli.py in __main__.py by using

```
import .cli as clifunc
```

but it results in an error

```
root@localhost:~# python3 -m pkg
import .cli as clifunc
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I import the file? Other methods I've tried resulted in the error being that the file isn't a module!?! How can I just import the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-do-i-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently when using the explicit relative imports (using dots like `.cli`), you can't just use `import .module` (not sure quite why though, maybe someone else does)

You instead need to use `from . import module`

So `from . import cli as clifunc` should work.